# How to create UUID numbers only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a UUID for a tuple of records in the database, and it is required that it is 10 digit numbers only.
Is there a way to do that in python?
The requirement is that it is a 10-digit guaranteed to be unique number, because it    connects a few rows to one id.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can I ask why it MUST be a UUID with only numbers and of length 10? If you only care about uniqueness, you can use `uuid.uuid4()`

Comment: If you are using Django, you need to add validators inside the `uuid` field.

Comment: Note that there's only 10^10 unique combinations of 10 digits (10 billion) which is not particularly high to guarantee uniqueness. If you have a million rows in a database for e.g., you'll likely have collisions. Generally UUIDs are 128-bit.

Comment: Create a random number between 0 and 10^10. Check if that number already exists, and restart from step 1 if necessary.

Comment: `f'{random.randint(0, 10**10 - 1):010d}'`

Comment: Expanding on my previous comment, UUIDs are 128-bit and thus have 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 possible IDs. Your 10 digit number only allows for 10000000000 possible IDs. Why so restrictive?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds use `random` here is a bad idea. You'd like to use Secure Random instead.

Comment: @EirNym I mean, the whole thing is a bad idea if security is needed. With a ten digit number there's really no need to be picky otherwise (IMO). Still, your answer is better (and is why my suggestion was a comment).

Comment: We store these numbers to an external storage and secure random will fulfill uniqiness requirement here. UUIDv4 in Python uses secure random by default

Comment: 10 billion options is enough for the database I have, It just needs to be certain that it's unique, and I didn't know how else uniqueness would be guaranteed\.

Answer (score 1):

just read 5 random bytes from `os.urandom()` and do `mod 9999999999` next:

```
value = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(5), byteorder='little') % 9999999999
```